# Message signing with airgapped wallet that doesn't support it

Tags: hardware-wallet, message-signing, qrcode, bip174-psbt

I need to implement message signing for various HWs, many of them support it on a firmware level, but some airgapped wallets like SeedSigner or Jade still don't. I was wondering if there's a way to trick those wallets into signing some dummy PSBT and then use it as a proof of PK ownership? If yes how do I construct that PSBT. What do I use for input's witness data and txid?